# Find linebreaks in a docx file using PHP

Tags: php, ms-office, document

My PHP script successfully reads all text from a .docx file, but I cannot figure out where the line breaks should be so it makes the text bunched up and hard to read (one huge paragraph). I have manually gone over all of the XML files to try and figure it out but I cannot figure it out.

Here are the functions I use to retrieve the file data and return the plain text.

```
    public function read($FilePath)
{
    // Save name of the file
    parent::SetDocName($FilePath);

    $Data = $this->docx2text($FilePath);

    $Data = str_replace("<", "&lt;", $Data);
    $Data = str_replace(">", "&gt;", $Data);

    $Breaks = array("\r\n", "\n", "\r");
    $Data = str_replace($Breaks, '<br />', $Data);

    $this->Content = $Data;
}

function docx2text($filename) {
    return $this->readZippedXML($filename, "word/document.xml");
}

function readZippedXML($archiveFile, $dataFile)
{
    // Create new ZIP archive
    $zip = new ZipArchive;

    // Open received archive file
    if (true === $zip->open($archiveFile))
    {
        // If done, search for the data file in the archive
        if (($index = $zip->locateName($dataFile)) !== false)
        {
            // If found, read it to the string
            $data = $zip->getFromIndex($index);

            // Close archive file
            $zip->close();

            // Load XML from a string
            // Skip errors and warnings
            $xml = DOMDocument::loadXML($data, LIBXML_NOENT | LIBXML_XINCLUDE | LIBXML_NOERROR | LIBXML_NOWARNING);

            $xmldata = $xml->saveXML();
            //$xmldata = str_replace("</w:t>", "\r\n", $xmldata);
            // Return data without XML formatting tags
            return strip_tags($xmldata);
        }

        $zip->close();
    }

    // In case of failure return empty string
    return "";
}
```

Comment: In what order are these used? Is `return strip_tags($xmldata);` the returned data that does not contain the line breaks?

Comment: To use the code just call the read() method, and the data is stored in $this->Content.  The XML line breaks are there, but not for the document. Looking at the XML of the document is very confusing when trying to figure out any type of formatting.

Comment: Ah right yes. Does saveXML() remove it? I remember having to clone and then import a DOMDocument, then use XPath to query the main element and use nodeValue to get everything. This seems rather extreme - are you sure the line breaks are simply line breaks and not some Microsoft special syntax?

Comment: Hmm, I'm not really sure... I do not know anything about the DOMDocument. Have you ever looked at the XML structure of a DOCX file? It breaks up the document in weird ways, I cannot make out how it is possible to distinguish paragraphs by looking at the XML in the document, so I can't figure out how to make PHP do it.

Comment: Can you upload the XML - I don't have access to any docx files (Mac user)

Comment: @jakenoble Mac FTW! :)  Here is the link to the docx after renaming it .zip. The file word/content.xml has the main content. http://sandbox.zenorsoft.com/swift/docx.zip

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is actually quite a simple answer. All you need to do is add this line in `readZippedXML()`:

```
$xmldata = str_replace("</w:p>", "\r\n", $xmldata);
```

This is because </w:p> is what word uses to mark the end of a paragraph. E.g.

```
<w:p>This is a paragraph.</w:p>
<w:p>And a second one.</w:p>
```

Comment: I thought the same thing, which is why I added that line. But it ends up breaking up in the middle of words, which is really bad for the purpose of my site. (http://sandbox.zenorsoft.com/swift/index.php?page=swift&mode=view&id=60)

Comment: @MasterZ try using `</w:r>` instead

Comment: @MasterZ actually, `</w:p>` is what you are looking for. I will edit the answer

Comment: You should change that middle line ot </w:p> instead of t.

Comment: If it doesn't work then also add
`$xmldata = str_replace("<w:br/>", "\r\n", $xmldata);`

before: `return strip_tags($xmldata);`

Answer (score 0):

Actually, why don't you use OpenXML? I think it works with PHP too. And then you don't have to go down to the nitty gritty file xml details.

Here is a link:
http://openxmldeveloper.org/articles/4606.aspx

Comment: Updated my answer with a link. Basically it's an API from microsoft to create and edit docx and xlsx files.

Comment: Looks interesting but it may be more than I need. I do not need to edit a document or save, I just need to extract all text. Thanks for the info though.