# PHP read docx file content but keeping line breaks, italic, underline and bold?

Tags: php, domdocument, docx, strip-tags

How can I read docx content, stripping all tags but keeping these below?

1. Bold
2. Italic
3. Underline
4. New Line

Below is my code that I got from the other answers:

```
//FUNCTION :: read a docx file and return the string
// http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4587216/how-can-i-convert-a-docx-document-to-html-using-php
// https://www.jackreichert.com/2012/11/how-to-convert-docx-to-html/
function readDocx($filePath) {
    // Create new ZIP archive
    $zip = new ZipArchive;
    $dataFile = 'word/document.xml';
    // Open received archive file
    if (true === $zip->open($filePath)) {
        // If done, search for the data file in the archive
        if (($index = $zip->locateName($dataFile)) !== false) {
            // If found, read it to the string
            $data = $zip->getFromIndex($index);
            // Close archive file
            $zip->close();
            // Load XML from a string
            // Skip errors and warnings
            $xml = DOMDocument::loadXML($data, LIBXML_NOENT | LIBXML_XINCLUDE | LIBXML_NOERROR | LIBXML_NOWARNING);
            // Return data without XML formatting tags
            $xmldata = $xml->saveXML();
            // </w:p> is what word uses to mark the end of a paragraph. E.g.
            // <w:p>This is a paragraph.</w:p>
            // <w:p>And a second one.</w:p>
            // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5607594/find-linebreaks-in-a-docx-file-using-php
            $xmldata = str_replace("</w:p>", "\r\n", $xmldata);
            $xmldata = str_replace("<w:i/>", "<i>", $xmldata);

            $contents = explode('\n',strip_tags($xmldata, "<i>"));
            $text = '';
            foreach($contents as $i=>$content) {
                $text .= $contents[$i];
            }
            return $text;
        }
        $zip->close();
    }
    // In case of failure return empty string
    return "";
}

$filePath = 'sample.docx';
$string = readDocx($filePath);
var_dump($string);
```

So far I only manage to keep line breaks but not the rest:

```
$xmldata = str_replace("</w:p>", "\r\n", $xmldata);
$xmldata = str_replace("<w:i/>", "<i>", $xmldata); // will get <i>Hello World <-- no closing i
```

Any ideas?

**EDIT:**

```
$xmldata = preg_replace("/<w\:i\/>(.*?)<\/w\:r>/is", "<i>$1</i>", $xmldata);
$xmldata = preg_replace("/<w\:b\/>(.*?)<\/w\:r>/is", "<b>$1</b>", $xmldata);
$xmldata = preg_replace("/<w\:u (.*?)\/>(.*?)<\/w\:r>/is", "<u>$2</u>", $xmldata);
```

But the solutions above have flaws because for instance:

```
<w:r><w:t xml:space="preserve"><w:i/>Hello</w:t></w:r><w:r><w:t xml:space="preserve"> World</w:t></w:r>
```

You will notice I am replacing `<w:i/>` and `<\/w\:r>` because `<w:i/>` has not pair.

Any better solutions?

Answer (score 2):

I have these solutions - it is ugly but it works:

```
        $xmldata =
                    '<w:r>
        <w:rPr>
        <w:u/>
        <w:b/>
        <w:i/>
        </w:rPr>
        <w:t>I feel that there is much to be said for the Celtic belief that the souls of those whom we have lost are held captive in some inferior being...</w:t>
        </w:r>';
        // </w:p> is what word uses to mark the end of a paragraph. E.g.
        // <w:p>This is a paragraph.</w:p>
        // <w:p>And a second one.</w:p>
        // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5607594/find-linebreaks-in-a-docx-file-using-php
        // http://officeopenxml.com/WPtext.php
        $xmldata = str_replace("</w:p>", "\r\n", $xmldata);
        $xmldata = preg_replace("/<w\:i\/>(.*?)<w:t(.*?)>(.*?)<\/w\:t>/is", "<w:i/>$1<w:t$2><i>$3</i></w:t>", $xmldata);
        $xmldata = preg_replace("/<w\:b\/>(.*?)<w:t(.*?)>(.*?)<\/w\:t>/is", "<w:b/>$1<w:t$2><b>$3</b></w:t>", $xmldata);
        $xmldata = preg_replace("/<w\:u(.*?)\/>(.*?)<w:t(.*?)>(.*?)<\/w\:t>/is", "<w:u$1/>$2<w:t$3><u>$4</u></w:t>", $xmldata);
```

Output:

```
<u><b><i>I feel that there is much to be said for the Celtic belief that the souls of those whom we have lost are held captive in some inferior being...</i></b></u>
```

Comment: Cool! How about text alignment? Any ways to also keep center-align, right-alignb etc.? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a need of those `str_repalce()` and `explode()` functions hence I do one single `strip_tags()`:

```
$contents = strip_tags($xmldata, '<w:p><w:u><w:i><w:b>');
```

By now you are sure all desired tags are preserved. Taking another step, we should replace `<w:*>` tags with their corresponding HTML tags:

```
$contents = preg_replace("/(<(\/?)w:(.)[^>]*>)\1*/", "<$2$3>", $contents);
```

We have only HTML tags with one character in their names `<p>`, `<b>`, `<i>`, `<u>` so capturing their names is as simple as using a ***dot capturing group***:

```
 (               # (1 start)
      <             # Match XML opening tag character           
      ( \/? )       # (2) Match if it is going to be an ending tag
      w:            # Literal `w:`
      ( . )         # (3) Match b,p,u,i
      [^>]* >       # Up to closing tag character
 )               # (1 end)
 \1*             # Match if latter group repeats
```

I had to check for same matched tags `\1*` because I found out it has high possibility to happen. If our docx file contains three lines like below:

**Bold**

*Italic*

Normal

Then at this point our output is similar to this:

```
<p><b><b>Bold</p><p><i><i>Italic</p><p>Normal</p>
```

But as you can see, we have unpaired duplicated tags which is not good at all. We should clean up our document. But how?

1. By PHP Tidy extension
2. Load our HTML into a `DOMDocument` object

Although PHP Tidy is great for this kind of job, I found `DOMDocument` more suitable for doing our task:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
@$dom->loadHTML($contents, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED  | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
$contents = $dom->saveHTML();
```

We have two related flags set since we don't need HTML `DOCTYPE` as well as `<html>`/`<body>` tags.

Our output at this point:

```
<p><b><b>Bold</b></b><p><i><i>Italic</i></i></p><p>Normal</p></p>
```

The good news is now we have paird tags but it might be a bad news that we have unnecessary opened tags:

```
<p><b><b>Bold</b></b><p><i><i>Italic</i></i></p><p>Normal</p></p>
   ^  ^                 ^  ^
```

For a working solution around removing extra opening tags, I wrote another RegEx:

```
$contents = preg_replace('~<([ibu])>(?=(?:\s*<[ibu]>\s*)*?<\1>)|</([ibu])>(?=(?:\s*</?[ibu]>\s*)*?</?\2>)|<p></p>~s', "", $contents);
```

What it is going to do can be seen here:

```
 <                                  # Match an opening tag
 ( [ibu] )                          # (1) Any type except `p`
 >                                  # Up to closing character
 (?=                                # Which is immediately followed by
      (?: \s* < [ibu] > \s* )*?     # Another opening tag (or nothing)
      < \1 >                        # And then its own closing tag.
 )                                  # End of lookahead
 |                                  # Or match
 </                                 # A closing tag
 ( [ibu] )                          # (2) Any type except `p`
 >                                  # Up to closing character
 (?=                                # Which is immediately followed by
      (?: \s* </ [ibu] > \s* )*?    # Another closing tag (or nothing)
      </? \2 >                      # And then the same closing tag
 )                                  # End of lookahead
 |                                  # Or match
 <p></p>                            # Empty <p> tags
```

Now we have the right output:

```
<p><b>Bold</b><p><i>Italic</i></p><p>Normal</p></p>
```

Putting all things together:

```
<?php

function readDocx($filePath) {
    // Create new ZIP archive
    $zip = new ZipArchive;
    $dataFile = 'word/document.xml';
    // Open received archive file
    if (true === $zip->open($filePath)) {
        // If done, search for the data file in the archive
        if (($index = $zip->locateName($dataFile)) !== false) {
            $data = $zip->getFromIndex($index);
            $zip->close();

            $dom = new DOMDocument;
            $dom->loadXML($data, LIBXML_NOENT
                | LIBXML_XINCLUDE
                | LIBXML_NOERROR
                | LIBXML_NOWARNING);

            $xmldata = $dom->saveXML();

            $contents = strip_tags($xmldata, '<w:p><w:u><w:i><w:b>');
            $contents = preg_replace("/(<(\/?)w:(.)[^>]*>)\1*/", "<$2$3>", $contents);

            $dom = new DOMDocument;
            @$dom->loadHTML($contents, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED  | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
            $contents = $dom->saveHTML();

            $contents = preg_replace('~<([ibu])>(?=(?:\s*<[ibu]>\s*)*?<\1>)|</([ibu])>(?=(?:\s*</[ibu]>\s*)*?</?\2>)|<p></p>~s', "", $contents);

            return $contents;
        }
        $zip->close();
    }
    // In case of failure return empty string
    return "";
}

$filePath = 'sample.docx';
$string = readDocx($filePath);
echo $string;
```

Comment: Thanks! But what the bold/italic is not for the whole paragraph? Currently the style would apply to the whole paragraph after the opening tag.

Answer (score 0):

stripping tags is no good way, because with your current solution you don't get the end of formating - you should think about interpreting xml instead

the other tags you searching for are `<w:b/>` (bold) and `<w:u ...>` (underline)